# foreach and section in smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I am using smarty and trying following code...

**php**

```
  foreach($forum_sections as $key => $val){

  $smarty->assign($key, $categories->Catgs_for_section($key));
}
```

so you have got an idea i am assigning arrays using foreach for template...

**smarty/template code**

```
    {foreach from=$forum_sections key=k item=forum_section}
<div class="forumcat">
    <h2>{$forum_section}</h2>

      {section name=tmp loop=$k}  
          <ul>
            <li><a class="title" href="#">{$k[tmp].title}</a></li>
          </ul>
      {/section}    

          </div><!--/forumcat -->
{/foreach}
```

but its not working, i think it may be problem in smarty code, please help and let me know if you have any question.

Comment: Smarty looks soooooooooo useful...

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution: I have replaced it with `{${$k}[tmp].title}` and it worked.

Answer (score -2):

First of all, why are you assigning sections by key as a variable? You end up with a bunch of variables in your template and not use them.

Secondly, in your template you try to iterate over key.. and key $k is always string, so it can't have a title.

Comment: i have main sections in array, and would like to get all sub categories($categories->Catgs_for_section($key)) for all sections, so what's the solution?

Comment: Well you could pass entire object and call methods from template, but I consider it a bad practice. Another solution is to aggregate subcategories first in an array and then pass this array in template for iteration. I understood what you were trying to do, you could try {$$k[tmp].title} instead

Comment: can you post an example please for aggregate subcategories first in an array and then pass this array in template

Comment: its throwing error if i use {$$k[tmp].title} but you got idea what i am trying to do, i know its trick, but would be best in this.